# Objective c - how can I add checked/unchecked value of checkbox in array

Tags: objective-c, checkbox

I want to save value TRUE if checkbox checked, and FALSE if it is unchecked in an array, how can I do that. I have implemented checkbox in tableview. Code is,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL checked = [[checkedArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    [checkedArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cheval insertObject:(checked) ? @"FALSE":@"TRUE" atIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_bg.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.accessoryView=button;
}
```

Comment: Did you try the above code? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
[cheval insertObject:(checked) ? @"FALSE":@"TRUE" atIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This currently adds a string representation of the value to the `cheval` array. You can change this to:

```
[cheval insertObject:@(checked) atIndex:indexPath.row];
```

To change the string to an `NSNumber` (so you can call `boolValue` on it).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[array2 insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[checkButton state]] atIndex:indexPath.row];
```

checkButton is outlet of check box.

Answer (score 0):

1. NSMutableArray is not like C array. It's more like a list. So

   BOOL checked = [[checkedArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
   [checkedArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

will not work like you want.

1. Also `[cheval insertObject:(checked) ? @"FALSE":@"TRUE" atIndex:indexPath.row];` will crash if `cheval` contains less objects than `indexPath.row`.

I would suggest using `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `NSMutableArray`. You may use an `NSIndexPath` object as a key. And change a little bit algorithm:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathKey = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]; // we use this code because in iOS 7 indexPath has type UIMutableIndexPath
    BOOL checked = ![checkedDict[indexPathKey] boolValue];
    checkedDict[indexPathKey] = @(checked);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_bg.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.accessoryView=button;
}
```

Also why don't you use default checkmark. If you use it you should change your code in the following way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathKey = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]; // we use this code because in iOS 7 indexPath has type UIMutableIndexPath
    BOOL checked = ![checkedDict[indexPathKey] boolValue];
    checkedDict[indexPathKey] = @(checked);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = checked ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: I want to use a custom checkmark , so that small icon will be displayed as checked and other image as unchecked.